# JPA : How to handle mapping with a table that has relationship with two other tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have three tables, **table A** (product), **table B** (invoice) and **table C** (invoices_info) which contains two columns referencing `invoice_id` and `product_id`. How can i insert a new entry (a new invoice) while inserting the products to the appropriate table and inserting the invoice info to its table also ?

Here are the entity classes :
**Product**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "family_id")
private long familyId;   
@Column(name = "product_name")
private String productName;
@Column(name = "product_category")
private String productCategory;
@Column(name = "product_quantity")
private int productQuantity;
//getters and setters
}
```

**Invoice**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
public class Invoice {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "invoice_id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "provider_id")
private Long providerId;
@Column(name = "total")
private int invoiceTotal;
@Column(name = "date")
private Date invoiceDate;
//getters and setters
}
```

**InvoiceInfo**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice_info")
public class InvoiceInfo {


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "item_id")
private long id;   
@Column(name = "product_id")
private long productId;
@Column(name = "invoice_id")
private long invoiceId;


//getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

InvoiceInfo should be join table, Define relationship on entities Product & Invoice using annotations @OneToMany, @ManyToOne based on your requirement.

Comment: As presented in the question, `invoice_info` does look like a join table, but probably for a many-to-many relationship, not many-to-one / one-to-many.  However, I speculate that the *real* `InvoiceInfo` has additional persistent properties, in which case it would indeed need to be an entity in its own right.  That entity would have mapped one-to-many relationships with both Product and Invoice.  Likely the relationship with `Product` would be unidirectional, but probably the one with Invoice would need to be bidirectional.

Comment: Yes, you got me, i already tried mapping in that way, but product_id and invoice_id are both like foreign keys referencing id in Product and id in Invoice. So the persistance here is a little bit confusing, which one i should save first into the database, in other words; what's the best approach to add a new entry, note that letting down the invoice_info table is not really a good idea since it will prevent duplicating data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create relationships between your entities by using a set of annotations like: `@ManyToOne`, `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToOne`... and other annotations if needed.

In your case I am not really sure you need an `InvoiceInfo` table, as the `Invoice` table can (or should) already contains the list of products.

I would suggest you the following relationships:

**Product**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "family_id")
    private long familyId;   
    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String productName;
    @Column(name = "product_category")
    private String productCategory;
    @Column(name = "product_quantity") 
    private int productQuantity;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Invoice invoice;
    //getters and setters
}
```

**Invoice**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "invoice_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "provider_id")
    private Long providerId;
    @Column(name = "total")
    private int invoiceTotal;
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date invoiceDate;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    private List<Product> products;
    //getters and setters
}
```

As your table `InvoiceInfo` no longer exists, you just have to insert you data in two table like this:

```
Invoice invoice = invoiceRepository.save(invoice);
Product product = new Product();
// Set the other properties
product.setInvoice(invoice);
productRepository.save(product);
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but in this case, i'll have unnecessary duplicate data like invoice_date, provider_id and invoice_total. Imagin i have an invoice with a hundred of products, in every record i'll get unncessary repeated values of (invoice_date, invoice_total, provider_id) . I could go for  only one table that represent Products with some additional columns if that was what i'm looking for.